# What is the support of AVX-512 in MacBookAir9,1

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu

This could be checked if you have the new 2020 MacBook Air by using command:

```
sysctl -a | grep cpu
```

I am not in possession of this Mac and can not find this documented by Apple or elsewhere online.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Anandtech article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/15635/apple-reveals-macbook-air-2020-10th-gen-quadcore-iris-plus-scissor-keyboard-16-gb-2-tb) and [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html) site it looks like they have it:

[Core i3-1000ng4](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196586/intel-core-i3-1000ng4-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz.html)

[Core i5-1030ng7](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196589/intel-core-i5-1030ng7-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html)

[Core i7-1060ng7](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196596/intel-core-i7-1060ng7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html)